# automake cannot deduce `_OBJECTS` from `_SOURCES` when using Pattern-Rules

Tags: automake

Automake usually can deduce object names needed for linking from the list of `_SOURCES`.

The following example using old-fashioned suffix rules works:

```
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4

bin_PROGRAMS = testam
testam_SOURCES = testam.c c.asn1

.asn1.c:
    > $@
```

_

```
$ rm -f testam && make
/bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2   -o testam.exe testam.o c.o
libtool: link: gcc -g -O2 -o testam.exe testam.o c.o
```

As you can see, automake added the file `c.o` to the list of objects required to build `testam`.

But `c.o` isn't added, if I try to convert the rule into a pattern-rule:

```
%.c: %.asn1
    > $@
```

_

```
$ rm -f testam && make
/bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2   -o testam.exe testam.o
libtool: link: gcc -g -O2 -o testam.exe testam.o
```

I have to use pattern rules, because my tool actually has two outputs: `%.c %.h: %.asn1`.

Why is this happening and how to explicitly add object files? Should I use `_DEPENDENCIES` and `_LDADD` or maybe `BUILT_SOURCES`?

## Update

Automake's dependency tracking does not work for object files added with:

```
foo_LIBADD: extra1.o extra2.o
```

`.Po` files are generated, but `Makefile` does not include them